# exporting chose funcitons/datatypes in Haskell

Tags: debugging, haskell

I am newbie when it comes to haskell. Tell me please, where the bug is ?

```
t :: Int -> Args
t k =  Args {
            replay = Nothing,
            maxSuccess = 100,
            maxDiscard = 22,
            maxSize = k
}
```

> ‘maxDiscard’ is not a (visible) field of constructor ‘Args’

Comment: In order to find this bug you would have to show us how `Args` is defined. The error indicates that the field `maxDiscard` isn't actually part of if its definition though.

Comment: In this file, there is no definion of `Args` (it is from Test.QuickCheck)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maxDiscard` should be [`maxDiscardRatio`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Test.html).

Comment: Additionally, I did forget define Bool field 'chatty'